# node js merging xlsx columns before converting to json

Tags: node.js, parsing, xlsx

I have this table:

[image: xlsx table]

I'm using xlsx sheet_to_json in order to parse the table,
  and I get something like that:

```
[ {id: "123", title: "John", __Empty: "Key", __Empty_1: "GA"}, 
{id: "543", title: "Rick", __Empty: "T", __Empty_1: "FR"},
{id: "233", title: "Leo", __Empty: "m", __Empty_1: "USA"}]
```

I want to merge the columns under "title" header into one column, containing the content of 
  the three column with a line break between them, in order to get something like that when 
  converting to json:

```
[ {id: "123", title: "John\nKey\nGA"}, 
{id: "543", title: "Rick\nT\nFR"},
{id: "233", title: "Leo\nm\nUSA"}]
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.map` to get what you are looking for. something like this

```js
const input = [{"id": "123", "title": "John", "__Empty": "Key", "__Empty_1": "GA"},
  {"id": "543", "title": "Rick", "__Empty": "T", "__Empty_1": "FR"},
  {"id": "233", "title": "Leo", "__Empty": "m", "__Empty_1": "USA"}];

const result = input.map(item => {
  return {
    "id": item.id,
    "title": `${item.title}\n${item.__Empty}\n${item.__Empty_1}`
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't want to use the __Empty, I want more significant name.